# Django queryset from raw SQL

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I want an equivalent of this sql query in Django

```
SELECT Gender, ServCode
  FROM [openimisproductTestDb_16_08_22].[dbo].[tblInsuree] 
  JOIN [openimisproductTestDb_16_08_22].[dbo].[tblServices] ON [openimisproductTestDb_16_08_22].[dbo].[tblInsuree].AuditUserID = [openimisproductTestDb_16_08_22].[dbo].[tblServices].AuditUserID
  WHERE Gender = 'F' 
  AND  ServCode = 'F4'
```

What I have tried:

```
def assisted_birth_with_cs_query(user, **kwargs):
    date_from = kwargs.get("date_from")
    date_to = kwargs.get("date_to")
    hflocation = kwargs.get("hflocation")

    format = "%Y-%m-%d"

    date_from_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_from, format)
    date_from_str = date_from_object.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

    date_to_object = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_to, format)
    date_to_str = date_to_object.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

    
    dictBase = {
        "dateFrom": date_from_str,
        "dateTo": date_to_str,
        }
    dictGeo = {}
    if hflocation and hflocation!="0" :
        hflocationObj = HealthFacility.objects.filter(
            code=hflocation,
            validity_to__isnull=True
            ).first()
        dictBase["fosa"] = hflocationObj.name

        claimItem = Insuree.objects.filter(
            validity_from__gte = date_from,
            validity_to__lte = date_to,
            **dictGeo,
        gender = 'F'
        ).count()
      
        data = Service.objects.filter(code = 'F4').count() | Insuree.objects.filter(gender = 'F').count() 
    
        dictGeo['health_facility'] = hflocationObj.id
        dictBase["post"]= str(data)
        
    return dictBase
```

I tried like that but the one just adds when I want the women included in the insured table and the F4 code contained in the service table. both tables have the auditUserID column in common

Comment: `I tried like that but the one just adds when I want the women included in the insured table and the F4 code contained in the service table.` needs to be rewritten so it is more comprehensible.  Please add a clear *question* and a description of what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you could add the models to better see the relations between Insuree and Service. Assuming it's a 1-M, I'd go with this query:

```
Service.objects.filter(code='F4', insuree__gender='F').count()
```